# Is this BFS implementation correct?

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I am learning data structures currently and I wrote a program for implementation BFS and I would like if someone could check this for me.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

# Left out the insert function here

    def BFS(self):
        data = []
        queue = []
        node = self.root
        queue.append(node)
        while len(queue) != 0:
            queue.reverse()
            node = queue.pop()
            data.append(node.val)
            if node.left:
                queue.append(node.left)
            if node.right:
                queue.append(node.right)
        return data

# Tree
#      10
#    6    15
#   3 8    20

tree = BST()
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(15)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(8)
tree.insert(20)


print(tree.BFS())
```

The return value I am expecting is

```
[10, 6, 15, 3, 8, 20]
```

but, the return value I am getting is

```
[10, 6, 15, 8, 20, 3]
```

Is this still correct? Because the way I understand this is that every node value should be returned from left to right on each level so I am not sure if my implementation is correct or not.

Comment: Add the `insert` method

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables in different moments. It is called `"print debuging"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> queue.reverse()
> node = queue.pop()
> ```

Reversing the list and popping the last element makes for a pretty janky queue, don't you think? You're not re-reversing it afterwards which is why you're getting the unexpected ordering changes.

You can pass `pop` an index to remove a specific item:

```
node = queue.pop(0)
```

Removing items from the beginning of a list is slow, though. Each time you do it every other item has to be shifted to the left one space. I recommend upgrading to a dedicated [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) data structure.